# "Width" of character on screen

Tags: c++, ncurses, codepoint

I'm using Ncurses to write text editor. I would like to know if there is a way to determine how many different characters can be placed on screen, where each of the character is encoded with UTF-8. For example when I get screen width of 10 and one row, I can put 10 characters of width 1 with values as below:

0123456789

But when I would like to put whole row of smiling faces I can only put 4 of those, on screen of size 10:

So in this example smiling face takes width of 2,5 on screen. I would like to know is there a way to determine width of character on the screen?

Comment: isn't that determined by the font you are using? only if each char is the same width, you are able to know beforehand how wide a certain number of chars will be.

Comment: related: [std::setw and unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49858446/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ncurses uses wcwidth to determine the number of columns that a "wide character" (usually a Unicode value) in a **`wchar_t`** uses.  That might not be the same as what the terminal actually does, but if your locale (`LC_CTYPE`, etc.) is set consistently with the terminal's capabilities and configuration, the results are fairly consistent.

While [`wcwidth`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcwidth.html) is a standard function, it is incompletely standardized (I could digress). Most implementations use tables that are updated periodically (one source of problems), terminal emulators may/may not be consistent, and ***fonts*** may not correspond to the values in `wcwidth`.

With all of that in mind, you can always ask ncurses (or some other implementation of X/Open Curses) how many columns on the screen it would use by writing into a window that you do not display.  Lynx does this for example, in [`LYStrExtent0`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/178bb762e0b5c5e40ebbee627862de2b7504a9f5/src/LYCurses.c#L2240):

```
/*
 * Determine the number of cells the given string would take up on the screen,
 * limited (in the case of wide characters) by the maxCells parameter.
 *
 * If the returnCellNum parameter is TRUE, return the number of cells;
 * otherwise, return the length (limited by the len parameter) of the prefix of
 * the string that fits in maxCells cells.
 */
```